# Rails text field as select field with look up

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have a model Item, that has_many Tags. 
I would like to make a form field on the Item form like a text field, where the solution looks up matching tags, when the use enters text. 
The user should be able to select multiple tags, but the user should not be able to select tags that does not exist in the system.

Basecamp is doing this in this screenshot for the "With" field, and Stackoverflow do it for the tag field.Can you help me how I do this?

[Screenshoot from Basecamp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hpaZ.jpg)

Comment: It's a rather off topic question. You will want a plugin. Try searching for "tag input". Here are Jquery and Bootstrap examples: http://textextjs.com/ https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/

Comment: Hi. It looks like exactly the solutions I was looking for. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this solution, which is exactly what I was looking for: 
https://github.com/tsechingho/chosen-rails

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a gem like acts-as-taggable-on (https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on), which is well suited to your stated requirements.

Comment: Hi @gwcodes. I have looked at acts-as-taggable-on, but  I did not find the option to limit it to predefined tags from another model, and I did not find the type ahead.